# Determine if a list of numbers forms an arithmetic sequence, using higher-order functions, lambda

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, sequence

How can I define a function that determines if a list of numbers is an arithmetic sequence, using `lambda`, and only either of the higher-order-functions `filter`, `map`, or `foldr` (but **not** `build-list`)?

I was thinking of forming a list of all the consecutive differences and then checking if they are all equal, but that would involve the `build-list` function.

Another approach I thought of was to use `foldr`, but I'm not sure how I can calculate the common differences between each consecutive term.

Comment: Nice assignment question!

Answer (score 0):

[`foldr`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=foldr#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldr%29%29) can be called with more than one argument lists. For instance, you can call it with the input list, and its `cdr`. Then in the combining function you'd find the difference and compare it to

```
(- (cadr xs) (car xs))
```

which you'd calculate in advance.

Unfortunately, both lists must be of the same length, so instead of plain `(cdr xs)` you'd have to use e.g.

```
;; (append (cdr xs) (list #f))
(foldr cons (list #f) (cdr xs))
```

and modify the combining function accordingly:

```
    (lambda (a b r) 
        (and (or .... 
                 (= (- b a) the-diff))
             r))
```

(`r` standing for *"recursive result"*).

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to use the `srfi/1` version of `map` (which allows uneven input lists, unlike the `racket/base` version), then it's really easy:

```
(require srfi/1)
(define (arithmetic-sequence? lst)
  (apply = (map - lst (cdr lst))))
```

If you're only able to use `racket/list` functions, then you'd have to do some list trimming:

```
(define (arithmetic-sequence? lst)
  (apply = (map - (drop-right lst 1) (cdr lst))))
```

Comment: ah, `drop-right!` of course! (didn't know it existed).... :) with it, `(apply = ...` can be replaced with `(null? (filter (not (= (car diffs) ...` to fully comply with the requirements. (and if `drop-right` isn't allowed, it can be reimplemented with `foldr` too).